# Add columns from a file to a specific position in another file

Tags: python

I have 3 files. In there header they all have `Id`'s. What I want to do is to find the intersecting `ID`'s (template is file 1) and then copy the columns with the correct `ID` behind the `ID` in the template-file.

Here is an example:

File 1 is the template:

```
name 123 124 125 128 131 145 156
rdt4 35  12  23  21  36  34  37
gtf2 24  18  18  29  26  12  40
hzt7 40  23  26  25  13  21  28
```

File 2:

```
name 123 124 125 126 127 128 131 132 133 145 156
rdt4 F   F   F   T   T   F   T   T   T   F   T
gtf2 F   F   F   T   T   F   T   T   T   F   T
hzt7 F   F   F   T   T   F   T   T   T   F   T
```

File 3:

```
name 123_a 123_b 123_c 124_a 124_b 124_c 125_a 125_b 125_c 126_a 126_b 126_c 127_a 127_b 127_c 128_a 128_b 128_c and so on
rdt4 0,087 0,265 0,632 0,220 0,851 0,271 0,436 0,148 0,080 0,899 0,636 0,467 0,508 0,460 0,393 0,689 0,427 0,798
gtf2 0,770 0,971 0,231 0,969 0,494 0,181 0,989 0,155 0,351 0,131 0,204 0,553 0,581 0,138 0,982 0,287 0,702 0,522
hzt7 0,185 0,535 0,093 0,807 0,487 0,786 0,886 0,905 0,966 0,283 0,490 0,190 0,688 0,714 0,577 0,643 0,476 0,738
```

The final file should look like this:

```
name 123 123 123_b 124 124 124_b 125 125 125_b 128 128 128_b 131 131 131_b 145 145 145_b 156 156 156_b
rdt4 35  F   0,265 12  F   0,851 23  F   0,148 21  F   0,427 36  T         34  F         37  T
gtf2 24  F   0,971 18  F   0,494 18  F   0,155 29  F   0,702 26  T         12  F         40  T
hzt7 40  F   0,535 23  F   0,487 26  F   0,905 25  F   0,476 13  T         21  F         28  T
```

Note: I skipped to type in everything for File 3 because it has the same numbers of ID's like file 2 but in file 3 every ID have 3 columns and I need only one of these columns (in the example column b).

What I tried so far:
I started first to do everything only with file 1 and file 2.
I copied the `ID`'s to a new list and then find the positions of these `ID`'s in file 2 to extract the data. But this seems to be very tricky (at least for me). The appending works so far but the problem is that every list which is stored in the list `final` is the same. It would be nice if you can help me with this.

This is my code so far:

```
try:
   Expr_Matrix_1="file1.txt"    
   #Expr_Matrix_1=raw_input('Name file with expression data: ')
   Expr_Matrix_2=open(Expr_Matrix_1)
   Expr_Matrix_3=open(Expr_Matrix_1)
except:
   print 'This is a wrong filename!'
   exit()


try:
   Probe_Detect_1="file2.txt"
   #Probe_Detect_1=raw_input('Name of file with probe detection: ')
   Probe_Detect_2=open(Probe_Detect_1)
   Probe_Detect_3=open(Probe_Detect_1)
except:
   print 'This is a wrong filename!'
   exit()


find_list=list()

for b, line2 in enumerate(Expr_Matrix_2):
    line2 = line2.rstrip()
    line2 = line2.split("\t")
    if b == 0:
        for item in line2:
             find_list.append(item)

find_list=find_list[7:]
find_list2=list()

for i, line in enumerate(Probe_Detect_2):
    line = line.rstrip()
    line = line.split("\t")
    if i == 0:
        for item in find_list:
            find_list2.append(line.index(item))

#print find_list2

index1=8
final=list()        

for b, line2 in enumerate(Expr_Matrix_3):
   line2 = line2.rstrip()
   line2 = line2.split("\t")
   for c, line in enumerate(Probe_Detect_3):
      line = line.rstrip()
      line = line.split("\t")
      if line2[b]==line[c]:
          for item in find_list2:
              if len(line2)<1551:
                  line2.insert(index1, line[item])
                  index1=index1+2
      final.append(line2)

print final[1]
```

The fist ID-column in file 1 is column 7 that's why I used the 7 for slicing.
The 1551 means the number of rows to which it should be copied but I think this is a complete wrong approach. However, I wanted to show you my try!

Another note: All files start with the name-column but between this column and the first ID-column there are some columns which shouldn't be considered. Because file 1 is the template those columns should also be in the final file.

What is the solution?

Comment: Why the finally file should look like that? what is the logic?

Comment: Because all three files contain different information for every ID and one name. It makes it easier to read. The files are very big!